# application built using jhipster 2 stuck on 'Initializing JMX Metrics' in 'prod' deployment - works fine using dev profile

Tags: production-environment, jhipster

I've created an application using jhipster 2.0. while running the application using mvn 'mvn spring-boot:run' the application works fine.

however, when I run using the prod profile `(mvn -Pprod spring-boot:run)`, the application is stuck at `'Initializing JMX Metrics'` - I piped the run to a log file

`'mvn -Pprod spring-boot:run > log.txt'` and the log seems to suggest an error starting tomcat context. can anyone suggest what might be causing this with the `'prod'` profile in jhipster.

> [INFO] com.ozay.backend.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing
>   Metrics JMX reporting SV [ERROR]
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter - Error
>   starting Tomcat context:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException [WARN]
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext
>   - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
>   [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>   [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
>   [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>   [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.ozay.backend.Application.main(Application.java:76) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Comment: Log is not complete it does not show the root exception cause.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch would be your Liquibase setup. Try dropping your database and get jhipster to recreate it.